# uwsgi application no json response when called from ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, uwsgi

Completely new at this but have created a uwsgi script which is serving json to the browser 
keywords.py 
if start this in this way

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --wsgi-file keywords.py
```

keywords.py

```
def application(env, start_response):
req = Request(env)

resp =  Response(content_type='application/json', charset='UTF-8')

args = paramHandler(req.params)

#resp.json =  fetchKeywords(args)
fetchK = fetchKeywords(args)
resp.json = fetchK    

return resp(env, start_response)
```

However if I call this via ajax (jQuery $.getJSON) it returns an empty response body 
Any suggestions why

If I print resp to console it is there?

Am I missing something - tried search uwsgi docs but no help

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228894/uwsgi-ajax-reading-a-request

Comment: For info switched to flask all worked